# keras style transfer example has an unexplained constant

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am following along the keras example for neural style transfer and in the style loss function they divide by the number 4, I have read the original paper by Gatys et al. and other articles in search of the meaning of this integer and its contribution to the whole pprocess and cannot find an explanation.

code is from: https://keras.io/examples/generative/neural_style_transfer/

Does anyone know what it is ?

```
 def style_loss(style, combination):
    S = gram_matrix(style)
    C = gram_matrix(combination)
    channels = 3
    size = img_nrows * img_ncols
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(S - C)) / (4.0 * (channels ** 2) * (size ** 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find why they doing it in the original paper of [A Neural Algorithm of Artistic Style](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.06576), in short, people doing it mainly because after the calculate gradient of loss the constant value will be cancel out, so the formula will looking nicer.

[image]

`Flij` is the activation of the i filter at position j in layer l

[image]

`Nl` and `Ml` are number of feature maps and the height times the width of the feature map at layer l, `El` is style loss at layer l

[image]

As you can see, the constant value is cancel out

Of course you could do the math without cancel out the constant value for gradient, after all it just a constant value, will not have much effect on result

Paper did the same to the content loss as to the style loss:

[image]

[image]

`Plij` is content image's feature representation in layer l

While code in [keras example of neural style transfer](https://keras.io/examples/generative/neural_style_transfer/) did not cancel out the constant value for content loss:

```
def content_loss(base, combination):
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(combination - base))
```

Or you could think as it cancel out constant value using `content_weight`:

```
loss = loss + content_weight * content_loss(
    base_image_features, combination_features
)
```